# Getting error after deleting data, Notice: Undefined index: search

Tags: php

well,this is my error, the data successfully deleted, but the error come out..
here is my search.php coding. The error at the line 30

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("kuih2") or die("database could not connect ");
?>
```

html code for search.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete
    Record" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Search Student Record</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1><u>Student Database</u></h1></center>
    <form name="search" method="post" action="search.php">
    <table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px"
    align="center" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:
    20px">Search</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enter Search Keyword</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="search" size="40" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#666666" style="color:#FFFFFF">
    <td>Roll & class</td>
    <td>Name & Father's Name</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

search.php coding

```
<?
    $search=$_POST["search"];//the error is here
    $flag=0;
    $query="select * from itemorder where id like '%$search%' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $flag=1;
    echo "<tr ><td>",$row[0],", ",$row[1],"</td><td><a
    href='view.php?id=",$row[0],"'>",$row[2],", ",$row[3],"</a></td><td><a
    href='edit.php?id=",$row[0],"'>Edit</a> | <a
    href='del.php?id=",$row[0],"'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
    if($flag==0)
    echo "<tr><td colspan='3' align='center' style='color:red'>Record not
    found</td></tr>";
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <th colspan="3" align="right"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

then this my del.php coding...

```
<?
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("kuih2") or die("database could not connect ");
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete
    Record" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Add Student Record</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $query="delete from itemorder where id=$id";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo "<center>Successfully Deleted</center>";
    include("search.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: What is line 30? And what's the error?

Comment: Please post the actual error and we might be able to help you.

Comment: A very secure site... Can you try call `del.php?id=1 OR true`? For the science...

Comment: @WayneWhitty the error is Notice: Undefined index: search

Comment: `$_POST["search"]` doesn't get submitted. Check your form code and make sure you enter something into the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because after deleting you are including a file like this

```
 <?
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $query="delete from itemorder where id=$id";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo "<center>Successfully Deleted</center>";
    //include("search.php"); // I have commented this line
    ?>
```

The search.php file requires a **`POST`** parameter which you are **`not`** sending. Thus the error.

**Solution :** Comment the **`include`** at the end.

Comment: I suggest to improve your answer securing `$id` this way: `$id = (int)$_GET["id"];`.

Comment: Shankar Damodaran add the comment at the include("search.php");? it's not working

Comment: what should i do? remove the include("search.php"); ?

Comment: Yes that will be a good idea or just comment it like i have shown you on the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["search"])){
$search=$_POST["search"];
}
```

Comment: well i get the error at $query="select * from itemorder where id like '%$search%' ";
undefined variable:search

Comment: Because your trying to retrieve the value before submitting the form..That's pointless..I guess you are trying to retrieve the item based on user search..If so then use `ajax` to get item list from database..